# Dot notation for reaching the proprer child of JSON in $http request of Angular is not working?

Tags: http, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I POST a command to the server and server gives me the response back. My POST command works properly because I put the response in an alert view and it returns it as a JSON, so I can see the response inside of the alert view.

Here is the my code:

```
var appControllers = angular.module('app', ['jsonService']);
appControllers.controller('post', function($scope, $http) {

            $http({
                withCredentials: true,
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://myURL/command',
                data : 'myData',
                headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
                }
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        var JSONData = JSON.stringify(data);
                        $scope.persons = JSONData;
                           alert(JSONData);// assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                         alert(status);
                });
    });
```

My Question:
I want to parse one specific item inside of the JSON. I know I should use dot notation to reach the appropriate child of the JSON but I it's not working if I use dot notation.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul data-ng-controller="post">
        <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <div><a href="http://button2" data-role="button" ng-bind="person.firstName"></a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Any tip or help would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
  var JSONData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

And just use "data".  You are converting your javascript object back into a string.  You want to use it as an object.

```
  $scope.persons = data;
```